# How to Interpolate JSON Array having template variable with other JSON Object efficiently in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, json, data-structures

```
template = [
  {
    records: [
      { key: "Roll No", value: "${student1.rollNo}" },
      { key: "Class", value: "${student1.class} standard" },
    ],
  },
    {
    records: [
      { key: "Roll No", value: "${student2.rollNo}" },
      { key: "Class", value: "${student2.class} standard" },
    ]
  }
];

replacers={
   student1:{
      rollNo:100,
      class:10
   },
   student2:{
      rollNo:101,
      class:12
   }
}
```

```
template=[
  {
    records: [
      { key: "Roll No", value: "100" },
      { key: "Class", value: "10 standard" }
    ],
  },
    {
    records: [
      { key: "Roll No", value: "101" },
      { key: "Class", value: "12 standard" }
    ]
  }
];
```

After Interpolate / Mapping JSON array will be like above: (Without using any third party packages)

template=[
{
title: "Student 1",
records: [
{ key: "Roll No", value: "100" },
{ key: "Class", value: "10 standard" }
],
},
{
title: "Student 2",
records: [
{ key: "Roll No", value: "101" },
{ key: "Class", value: "12 standard" }
]
}
];

Comment: Please note that none of the data is JSON

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you :D

```js
function render(index, item){
    return {
    title: `Student ${index}`,
    records: [
      { key: "Roll No", value: `${item.rollNo}` },
      { key: "Class", value: `${item.class} standard` },
    ],
  }
}

const data=[
   {
      rollNo:100,
      class:10
   },
   {
      rollNo:101,
      class:12
   }
]

const res = data.map( (item, index) => render(index+1, item))

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I need a solution for below format                                                       
  const data={
    student1:{
      rollNo:100,
      class:10
   },
   student2:{
      rollNo:101,
      class:12
   }
}

Comment: Even fields inside the object may vary -  
 ----------------------------------------------
const data= 
{ 
  student:{ 
     rollNo:100, 
  class:10 
  },
  employee:{ 
  empNo:1000, 
  shift:day 
  } 
}
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
template = [
  {
    records: [
      { value: "${student.rollNo}" },
      { value: "${student.class} standard" },
    ],
  },
    {
    records: [
      { value: "${employee.empNo}" },
      { value: "${employee.shift} shift" },
    ]
  }
];

Answer (score 0):

**I have the solution for my problem, is there any efficient way we can get the same result**

```
        title: "Student 1",
        records: [{
                key: "Roll No",
                value: "${student1.rollNo}"
            },
            {
                key: "Class",
                value: "${student1.class} standard"
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        title: "Student 2",
        records: [{
                key: "Roll No",
                value: "${student2.rollNo}"
            },
            {
                key: "Class",
                value: "${student2.class} standard"
            },
        ]
    }
];

const data = {
    student1: {
        rollNo: 100,
        class: 10
    },
    student2: {
        rollNo: 101,
        class: 12
    }
}


var templateString = JSON.stringify(template);

for (var key in data) {
    for (var innerKey in data[key]) {
        if (data[key].hasOwnProperty(innerKey)) {
            var val = data[key][innerKey];
            templateString = templateString.split('${' + key + '.' + innerKey + '}').join(val);
        }
    }
}

template=JSON.parse(templateString);
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, You want to bind the object values dynamically based on the title in a template instead of hard coding the values. If Yes, here you go **:**

```js
const template = [
  {
    title: "Student 1",
    records: [
      { key: "Roll No", value: "" },
      { key: "Class", value: " standard" },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: "Student 2",
    records: [
      { key: "Roll No", value: "" },
      { key: "Class", value: " standard" },
    ]
  }
];

const replacers = {
  student1:{
    rollNo:100,
    class:10
  },
  student2:{
    rollNo:101,
    class:12
  }
};

template.forEach(obj => {
  Object.keys(replacers).forEach(key => {
    if (key === obj.title.replace(' ', '').toLowerCase()) {
      const innerKeys = Object.keys(replacers[key]);
      obj.records.forEach((o, i) => {
        o.value = replacers[key][innerKeys[i]] + o.value 
      })
    }
  })
});

console.log(template);
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, seems title confuses all. now updated the question. please check my solution down, just checking whether we can provide better solution